# Rars1_5 "Store address not aligned to word boundary"

Tags: assembly, linked-list, riscv, rars-simulator

so as you see from the title im facing a problem where i use the `sw`  command to initialize a "dummys" data to 0 so i can store letter something else. This is my code, i also used `sb` but i got the "out of range" error.

```
main:
            addi a7,x0,9  # Direction to ecall for memory allocation
            addi a0,x0,8  # a0 specifies size for allocation
            ecall
            # a7 contains the pointer to newly allocated Memory
            sw x0,0(a7) # dummy's data = zero
            sw x0,4(a7) # dummy's pointer = zero
```

im using `.align 2` before main, can anybody tell me why im getting this error?

Comment: What makes you think that `a7` has the `ecall #9` result?  RARS has [`help`](https://github.com/TheThirdOne/rars/wiki/Environment-Calls) for this.

Comment: `.align 2` before `main` would align your code, not your data.  The fact that `sb` reports out-of-range is a clear sign that `a7` is *not* the return value.

Comment: https://github.com/TheThirdOne/rars/wiki/Environment-Calls documents the ABI for RARS system calls.